# How to include domain user in Jenkins Job execution

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, dns, continuous-deployment

I am automating a build process. The process requires deployment of application to a server, after deployment a few scripts have to be executed to share and provide permissions on the server. The scripts run when I login via domain user through powershell.I am using Jenkins for the CI/CD process. I want to include my domain credentials to run the scripts on the server. I have also used the active directory plugin, and can login with my domain credentials but still I am not able to establish a remote connection with the server.

My script is

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ATKT-WS-20
Invoke-Expression -Command .\FolderSharingScript.ps1
```

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server ATKT-WS-20 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot 
>   process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x8009030e occurred while using Kerberos authentication: A 
>   specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
>    Possible causes are:
>     -The user name or password specified are invalid.
>     -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
>     -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
>     -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
>     -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
>    After checking for the above issues, try the following:
>     -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
>     -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or 
>   use HTTPS transport.
>    Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.<

I have also added the machine name in the trustedhosts. How can I include the domain credential in Jenkins jobs?

Comment: As an aside, irrespective of the credentials problem: `Enter-PSSession` is meant for _interactive_ use. Instead, either use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` for a one-off command or create a session object with `New-PSSession` for use with multiple `Invoke-Command -Session` calls.

Comment: nope, doesnt work

Comment: I know: that's why I classified my comment as an _aside_ and  said "irrespective of the credentials problem": it's an adjustment you need to make, but by itself it is not enough to fix your problem; you still need to solve the credentials problem - see next comment.

Comment: Some high-level pointers: (a) run the Jenkins service as the domain user (probably not a good idea), (b) install a Jenkins agent on the target machine and run it in the context of the domain user, then use the Jenkins PowerShell plugin to directly run the code of interest, (c) use the DPAPI to save credentials in the context of the user in which the Jenkins service runs to a file (which may be a challenge for the default `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` (LocalSystem) account), then construct a `[pscredential]` instance from that to pass to `-Credential`; (d) consider use of SSH with a private-key file.

Comment: (a) I am running Jenkins as the domain user, but still not working.
I will try the other options as well. SSH might be a good option

Comment: When you try (b), be sure that your job explicitly targets the target machine's agent.

Comment: I did the (b) but now I am getting this error

`Connecting to remote server ATKT-WS-20 failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For 
more information`
I have set the winrm service on the server and enabled PSRemoting, still it wont work.

Comment: If you use (b), do not use PS remoting at all - Jenkins has its own remoting, and as long as an agent machine is connected, you can send PS code as-is to it - no sessions, no credentials.

Comment: Ah yes. Its working now. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be not to use *PowerShell*'s remoting at all, but instead **rely on the remoting built into *Jenkins***:

- Connect the remote machine as a Jenkins agent to the Jenkins server, running the agent executable as the desired domain user.
- On the Jenkins server, ensure that your job is configured to run on the remote machine, using a label expression.
- Assuming the PowerShell plugin is installed, you can then send PowerShell code as-is to the remote machine - no need for PowerShell sessions, credentials, ...